# Using jq as a non json formatter

Tags: json, jq

I have some json input that looks like:

```
{
  "vers": "2.0",
  "result": [
    {
      "name": "Petes corner store",
      "address": [
        "LOCKED BAY 222",
        "Sydney",
        "9876"
      ],
      "dbno": "201449",
      "segments": [
        {
          "val": "23.40",
          "lines": [
            {
              "val": "11.40",
              "products": [
                {
                  "name": "Product 1",
                  "qty": "2",
                  "price_ea": "4.62",
                  "extended": "9.24"
                },
                {
                  "name": "Prod desc 2",
                  "qty": "18",
                  "price_ea": "0.12",
                  "extended": "2.16"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "val": "16.00",
          "lines": [
            {
              "val": "16.00",
              "products": [
                {
                  "name": "Product 3",
                  "qty": "3",
                  "price_ea": "4.00",
                  "extended": "12.00"
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }  
      ]
    }
  ],
  "id": 1
}
```

The data has a variable length of result, segments and lines arrays. I am trying to format the non json output to look something like:

```
COMMENT|Petes corner store|201449
SPOT|addr|\@lbl|LOCKED BAY 222|Sydney|9876
TABLE|Product 1|2|4.62|9.24
TABLE|Prod desc 2|18|0.12|2.16
BREAK
TABLE|Product 3|3|4.00|12.00
BREAK
FLUSH
```

Where the TABLE entries are a list of the extracted segments[].lines[].products[] kept in the same order with a divider between each segment. I was trying to use a single jq script to do the whole job that is basically:

```
.result |
keys[] as $k |
"COMMENT|\(.[$k] | "\(.name)|\(.dbno)"  )
SPOT|addr|\\@lbl|\(.[$k].address  | join("|") )
TABLE|Cant figure this out...
FLUSH
"
```

I thought this would be a good time to learn jq as I have written this in bourne shell and it works but its not very elegant.
So, any pointers on getting my TABLE entries working??

Answer (score 0):

With your input, the following jq program produces results which are very similar to what you indicated is expected:

```
.result[0]
| ["COMMENT", .name, .dbno],
  (["SPOT", "addr", "\\@lbl"] + .address),
  ( .segments[].lines[].products[] as $p
   | ((["TABLE"] + [$p[]]),
      ["BREAK"])),
  ["FLUSH"]

| join("|")
```

Namely:

```
COMMENT|Petes corner store|201449
SPOT|addr|\@lbl|LOCKED BAY 222|Sydney|9876
TABLE|Product 1|2|4.62|9.24
BREAK
TABLE|Prod desc 2|18|0.12|2.16
BREAK
TABLE|Product 3|3|4.00|12.00
BREAK
FLUSH
```

If the ordering of the keys in the product detail objects might not be the same, then you will probably want to specify the order rather than using `[$p[]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for taking the time to reply.

With the syntax tips given I was able to create a script that is doing exactly what I require. It has the BREAK lines correctly set only after each line array and it will work with multiple .result records in the array.

```
.result
| keys[] as $c
|
  ["COMMENT", (.[$c] | "\(.name), \(.dbno)" )],
  ["SPOT", "addr","\\@lbl"] + (.[$c].address),
  (
    (.[$c].segments | keys[]) as $s |
      (.[$c].segments[$s].lines | keys[]) as $l |
        (.[$c].segments[$s].lines[$l].products | keys[]) as $p |
          (if $p > 0 then ["BREAK"] else empty end),
          [
            "TABLE",
            .[$c].segments[$s].lines[$l].products[$p].name,
            .[$c].segments[$s].lines[$l].products[$p].qty,
            .[$c].segments[$s].lines[$l].products[$p].price_ea,
            .[$c].segments[$s].lines[$l].products[$p].extended
            ]
  ),
["FLUSH"]
| join("|")
```

There may be some optimizing that could be performed but this gives me a good foothold to work off.